# How to test in Mocha?

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, mocha.js, chai

I am new to writing test cases using Mocha. I have following functionality in my nodejs. I want to test this functionality but not getting an idea.

```
const notes = [];
if (this.note) { notes.push(this.note); }
if (message) { notes.push(message); }
```

Below is what I tried to implement

```
it("Approve the request", async () => {
    assert.notEqual(this.status, null);
    assert.notEqual(this.status, "Pending");
    expect(typeof const === []).to.be.true;// I got stuck here
    assert.ok(true);
  })
```

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: You test functions , or methods of objects if you are unit testing. Write the plain method down here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember test cases will come from your requirements, not your code. So it should cover all cases in your requirements, not your code. Your code needs to cover all requirements too.

So starting from the requirement, we would say:

1. The function should add note and message to the notes array.
2. The function should ignore note if note is empty.
3. The function should ignore message if message is empty.
4. The function should return empty array if both are empty.

So you can start writing your test based on those requirements